# Testing existance of tab

Tags: jquery

I am testing the existence of dynamic tabs in jQuery.  If it exists, select it, if not, create it.

This works 100% in FF, Chrome, etc.  I am new to jQuery, so I'm struggling to make this IE 8+ compatible.

```
    // Does the tab already exist?
    var checkName = satrk;
    var tabExists = false;
    $('#tabs ul li a').each(function(i) {
        if(this.text == checkName) {
            tabExists = true;
        }
    });

    // React to existance:
    if(!tabExists){
        $("#tabs").tabs("add","details.cfm?satrk="+satrk,satrk);
        $("#tabs").tabs("select", satrk); // select tab by index
    }else{
        $("#tabs").tabs("select", satrk); // select tab by index
    }
```

I pass the tabs index to the check.

Suggestions?

I read elsewhere that "An a element has no text property in IE." but that's not enough for me to correct my issue.

Comment: I should probably add, in FF it knows the index exists and selects the existing tab, in IE is fails to make a match and there for opens a new tab each time.

Comment: You could, instead, use: `this.innerText`: `if (this.text == checkName || this.innerText == checkName)` (but since you've got jQuery: `$(this).text()` will cover *all* cases, surely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
if($(this).text() == checkName) {
```

I think in your use, `this.text` is the `text` property of a DOM object. If you wrap that DOM object in jQuery (`$(this)`) then it should have a `.text()` method that will let jQuery sort out the cross browser stuff, and just return the text you want.

Comment: Hum, I am happy to say working, but frustrated as heck.  That same advice was given where I saw the "An a element has no text property in IE." I tried it, and it did not work.

So, either I mistyped and never saw it, or maybe a cache issue.  But this time, it worked as desired.  THANK YOU!  And sorry I asked a question already answered.